# rolled far to the westward

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of "rolled far to the westward" in the following passage? It is from the book “Persian Gulf Command” by Ashley Jackson, p288.

Churchill wrote to Brooke on 1 December 1942 that "the role of the Tenth Army is dependent upon the Russian defence of the Caucasus. Since we formed it in August a vast, favourable change has taken place, and it may be that before the end of the year all danger to Persia and Iraq will have rolled far to the westward"

Of course, the meaning is somehow clear: "the danger for Iran and Iraq will be eliminated", but "to the westward" is problematic. Does it mean the danger from west for these two countries will be eliminated? Or does it have another meaning?

Comment: I think he means that Turkey (or Syria) will be in danger.

Comment: It means that the battlefront would move westerly _towards_ the Mediterranean, or Egypt.

Comment: Imagine a carpet on the floor. You could start rolling up an old and dirty carpet towards the door in much the same way that "all danger to Persia and Iraq will have rolled far to the westward’" - clear ground is left behind. To roll expresses the consistent changing of circumstances, etc., over a wide area.

Comment: The fact that Churchill preceded "will have rolled far to the westward" with "a vast favourable change has taken place" indicates that the threat is likely to recede. "Will have rolled far to the westward", therefore, means that the Axis forces which threatened Iraq would have retreated in the direction of Europe or Africa.